# External log4j.xml file

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I am trying to run a jar with the log4j.xml file on the file system outside the jar like so:

```
java -jar MyJarName.jar -cp=/opt/companyName/pathToJar/ log4j.configuration=log4j.xml argToJar1 argToJar2
```

I have also tried:

```
java -jar MyJarName.jar -cp=/opt/companyName/pathToJar/ log4j.configuration=/opt/companyName/pathToJar/log4j.xml argToJar1 argToJar2
```

The log4j.xml is file is in the same directory as the jar (/opt/companyName/pathToJar/), yet I still get the standard warning message:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

Is it possible to have the config file outside the jar, or do I have to package it with the jar?

TIA

Answer (score 55, accepted):

When using the `-jar` switch to launch an executable jar file, the classpath is obtained from the jar file's manifest.  The `-cp` switch, if given, is ignored.

[Jeff Storey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594689/external-log4j-xml-file/2594704#2594704) is going to be the easiest solution. Alternatively, you could add a `Class-Path` attribute to the jar file's [manifest](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest).

**EDIT**
Try enabling log4j debugging, and making the path to `log4j.xml` a fully-qualified URL. For example:

```
java -Dlog4j.debug -Dlog4j.configuration=file:/path/to/log4j.xml -jar ...
```

Comment: I added this to the manifest and it still did not work (but I am not sure relative paths are legal):
Class-Path: .

Comment: java -Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/log4j.xml -jar MyJarName.jar <rest-of-args> perhaps the space between the Class-Path: and the '.' is to blame.

Comment: This helped me, the file attribute is something i was missing to put

Comment: This worked for me: -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./log4j.properties, it finds the properties file in the same directory as the startup script.

Comment: I faced the same issue with jdk 5. However , the issue was resolved when I moved to jdk6.

Comment: I've tried a few of these - and this is one that worked

Comment: for me, I had to define the file like this "file://{full path to log4j file}"

Answer (score 18):

this works:

```
java -jar -Dlog4j.configuration="file:d:\log4j.xml" myjar.jar
```

Answer (score 15):

For log4j2, use **configurationFile** option:

```
java -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/path/to/log4j2.xml -jar ...
```

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/configuration.html

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried `java -Dlog4j.configuration=/path/to/log4j.xml -jar <rest-of-args>`

Comment: need file: in front of the path

Answer (score 6):

you can define a default properties file in the jar. if no custom properties is defined you can use this default file.if a custom property is defined you can override the default property.

myjar.jar file contains log4j.default.configuration

you can run your program with this parameters to start your application

```
java  -jar -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties  target\yourfile-v01_000_01_c002.jar
```

Example code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filename = System.getProperty("log4j.configuration");
    if(null==filename||filename.trim().equals("")) {
        logger.info("Using default log4j configuration log4j.default.properties.");
        logger.info("If you would like to change the default configuration please add following param before startup -Dlog4j.configuration=<log4jfile>");
        PropertyConfigurator.configure( Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/log4j.default.properties"));
    } else {
        File file = new File(filename);
        if(!file.exists()) System.out.println("It is not possible to load the given log4j properties file :"+file.getAbsolutePath());
        else PropertyConfigurator.configure(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This works for .properties-file. If you use .xml configuration file then use DOMConfigurator instead of PropertyConfigurator.

Answer (score 2):

java -cp "path/to/your/log4jxml:path/to/yourjar.jar" your.package.MainClass

The log4j.xml in directory "path/to/your/log4jxml" will overwrite the log4j.xml file in "path/to/yourjar.jar".

Please refer to [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath).

Comment: This is worked for me.

Comment: Besides I had to pass jvm args like this: `-Dlog4j.configurationFile=/pathtoconf/log4j2.xml`

Answer (score 1):

I had problems using log4j with Sun's JDK and automatic configuration.

You can use this:

```
String filename = System.getProperty("log4j.configuration");
DOMConfigurator(filename);
```

before using Logger.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest path configuration for ``log4j2`is using the`static block`setting`log4j.configurationFile`:

```
public class MyClass {

    static {
        System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "./config/log4j2.xml");
    }

    protected final transient Logger logger =  LogManager.getLogger(IDOLTracker.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         logger.info("");
    }
}
```

Then the structure could be as:

> ProgramFolder
>    |---- /config/log4j2.xml
>    |---- MyClass.jar

When you run your jar, it will look outside the jar for the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

"-jar" only uses the classpath inside the executable jar, and -cp is ignored.  Adding "." to the classpath in the executable jar should allow log4j.xml to be found.