# Telling Tomcat which log4j.xml to Use

Tags: tomcat, log4j

Which setting do I specify in Tomcat so that I can pick a particular log4j.xml file?

I have a development and production log4j.xml file, so I'd like to be able to configure when to use one over the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add in your Tomcat config the following line:

```
TOMCAT_OPTS="-Dlog4j.configuration=/my/config/log4j.properties"
```

In your development environment you can override the default settings with this, and package your production config with the `war`.

Of course, if there are more properties in that variable, you must keep them :)

Comment: besides using the env var `TOMCAT_OPTS,` how would I specify which log4j.xml to use? Is it typically specified in `web.xml` or another config file?

Comment: Maybe you could read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716824/where-how-does-log4j-look-for-a-log4j-properties-file or that article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140358/how-to-initialize-log4j-properly