# How to set relative path for log4j.properties file in Websphere

Tags: java, log4j, websphere, jvm-arguments

Hi i am trying to set the log4j.properties path under websphere custom properties as a relative path which is not working.

**Setting Location:**

Middleware servers > cluster1node1 > Process definition > Java Virtual Machine > Custom properties

**This is working:**

```
 Property name: log4j.configuration
 Value: file:/dir1/dir2/my_configs/log4j.properties
```

**This is NOT working.**

```
 Property name: log4j.configuration 
 Value: ${CONFIG_ROOT}/my_configs/log4j.properties
```

Where config root is a websphere variable as below;

```
 Name: CONFIG_ROOT
 Value: /dir1/dir2/
```

Can someone tell me what possibly i am doing wrong here? I am able to use the similar relative path successfully for a normal application config file. Seems like this issue is applicable for just log4j.properties file.

**LATEST UPDATE:**

Actually the issue is more related to the filesytem as when i pre-fixed the relative path with **file:** it worked.

This is working now.

```
 Property name: log4j.configuration 
 Value: file:${CONFIG_ROOT}/my_configs/log4j.properties
```

But why is that? Why it is not working without **file:** ? And how to make it work without **file:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the log4j default initialization process explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716824/where-how-does-log4j-look-for-a-log4j-properties-file), log4j attempts to convert the value of **log4j.configuration** into a URL, thus the need for file:

Answer (score 0):

The issue was more related to the filesytem because when i pre-fixed the relative path with **file:** it worked.

This is working now.

```
 Property name: log4j.configuration 
 Value: file:${CONFIG_ROOT}/my_configs/log4j.properties
```